# concatenação de strings usando + em Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var nome= "João";
var sobrenome="Silva";
var idade=30;
var resultado= nome +"" + sobrenome + 'terá' +  idade  +""+ 'anos';
console.log(resultado);
```

o enunciado do exercício pede: declare uma variável com nome resultado e atribua uma string unindo suas variaveis da seguinte forma: " João Silva terá 30 anos" e utilize o console.log pra mostrar o que acontece. Respeite os espaços!

Criei o código mas está dando erro, o que tá errado?

Comment: O código tá certo, só falta os espaços. Ao invés de concatenar as strings com `""`, coloque o `" "` (Com um espaço entre as aspas). Os espaços contam como caracteres.

Comment: Oi! Uma sugestão, podias fazer assim para adicionar os espaços: `var resultado = [nome, sobrenome, 'terá', idade', 'anos'].join(' ');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código está correto, você esqueceu apenas dos espaços.

```js
var nome = "João";
var sobrenome ="Silva";
var idade = 30;
var resultado = nome + " " + sobrenome + ' terá ' +  idade  + ' anos';
console.log(resultado);
```

Agora dará certinho seu resultado!

Comment: obirgada, existe algum corretor de espaços de código online?

Comment: Nunca vi algo assim... Talvez seja mais fácil trabalhar com template strings, pois fica muito mais explícito como a sua string vai ficar, eu particularmente acho ótimo, caso não conheça, vale muito a pena dar uma olhada: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: Não existe pra esse problema. Na verdade, varia muito a utilização de espaços. Na prática não é muito comum ter problemas com isso. Você esqueceu de verificar os espaços nos textos que você criava para exibição no console. Não acho que acontecerá isso novamente. :)

Comment: @AnaPaula não tem sentido um corretor de código para espaços, pq concatenação pode ser qualquer coisa que formará uma string, isso ai não foi como um erro de ortografia, foi simplesmente falta de espaços.